# Ajuda a portar parte do código do Java para C++

Tags: java, c++, opengl

Estou em um projeto e minha 'responsabilidade' é portar o código de Java para C++ que utiliza OpenGL. Já fiz quase tudo, porém não funciona. Creio que o problema seja nessa classe que não consegui portar muito bem [eu mudei o código em java e deu o mesmo problema que acontece no código em C++: Nada aparece]. A minha dificuldade é entender como funciona esta classe "BufferUtils" e o "FloatBuffer". Creio que se fosse em C++ seria mais fácil [já programo com o OpenGL em C e C++ e já utilizei técnicas que funcionaram, mas este não =| ]

O código que estou com dúvida é este:

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

public class Tesselator
{
    private static final int MAX_VERTICES = 100000;
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer texCoordBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;
    private int vertices;
    private float u;
    private float v;
    private float r;
    private float g;
    private float b;
    private boolean hasColor;
    private boolean hasTexture;

    public Tesselator() {
        this.vertexBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(300000);
        this.texCoordBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(200000);
        this.colorBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(300000);
        this.vertices = 0;
        this.hasColor = false;
        this.hasTexture = false;
    }

    public void flush() {
        this.vertexBuffer.flip();
        this.texCoordBuffer.flip();
        this.colorBuffer.flip();
        GL11.glVertexPointer(3, 0, this.vertexBuffer);
        if (this.hasTexture) {
            GL11.glTexCoordPointer(2, 0, this.texCoordBuffer);
        }
        if (this.hasColor) {
            GL11.glColorPointer(3, 0, this.colorBuffer);
        }
        GL11.glEnableClientState(32884);
        if (this.hasTexture) {
            GL11.glEnableClientState(32888);
        }
        if (this.hasColor) {
            GL11.glEnableClientState(32886);
        }
        GL11.glDrawArrays(7, 0, this.vertices);
        GL11.glDisableClientState(32884);
        if (this.hasTexture) {
            GL11.glDisableClientState(32888);
        }
        if (this.hasColor) {
            GL11.glDisableClientState(32886);
        }
        this.clear();
    }

    private void clear() {
        this.vertices = 0;
        this.vertexBuffer.clear();
        this.texCoordBuffer.clear();
        this.colorBuffer.clear();
    }

    public void init() {
        this.clear();
        this.hasColor = false;
        this.hasTexture = false;
    }

    public void tex(final float u, final float v) {
        this.hasTexture = true;
        this.u = u;
        this.v = v;
    }

    public void color(final float r, final float g, final float b) {
        this.hasColor = true;
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void vertex(final float x, final float y, final float z) {

        this.vertexBuffer.put(this.vertices * 3 + 0, x);
        this.vertexBuffer.put(this.vertices * 3 + 1, y);
        this.vertexBuffer.put(this.vertices * 3 + 2, z);

        if (this.hasTexture) {
            this.texCoordBuffer.put(this.vertices * 2 + 0, this.u).put(this.vertices * 2 + 1, this.v);
        }
        if (this.hasColor) {
            this.colorBuffer.put(this.vertices * 3 + 0, this.r).put(this.vertices * 3 + 1, this.g).put(this.vertices * 3 + 2, this.b);
        }
        ++this.vertices;
        if (this.vertices == MAX_VERTICES) {
            this.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

E o código que eu "portei" foi este:

```
#ifndef TESSELATOR_HPP
#define TESSELATOR_HPP

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <vector>

#define MAX_VERTICES 100000

class Tesselator{
    std::vector<float> vertexBuffer = std::vector<float>();
    std::vector<float> texCoordBuffer = std::vector<float>();
    std::vector<float> colorBuffer = std::vector<float>();

    int vertices = 0;
    float u = 0;
    float v = 0;
    float r,g,b = 0;
    bool hasColor = false;
    bool hasTexture = false;

    public:

        Tesselator();

        void flush();
        void clear();
        void init();
        void tex(float u, float v);
        void color(float r, float g, float b);
        void vertex(float x, float y, float z);
};

#endif /* TESSELATOR_HPP */
```

---

```
#include "Tesselator.hpp"

Tesselator::Tesselator(){

    vertexBuffer.reserve(300000);
    texCoordBuffer.reserve(200000);
    colorBuffer.reserve(300000);

    init();
}

void Tesselator::flush(){

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertexBuffer[0]);

    if(hasTexture){
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &texCoordBuffer[0]);
    }
    if (hasColor){
        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &colorBuffer[0]);
    }
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    if(hasTexture)
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    if(hasColor)
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vertices);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    if(hasTexture)
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    if(hasColor)
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    clear();
}

void Tesselator::clear(){
    vertices = 0;

    //~ vertexBuffer.clear();
    vertexBuffer.resize(vertexBuffer.capacity());
    //~ texCoordBuffer.clear();
    texCoordBuffer.resize(texCoordBuffer.capacity());
    //~ colorBuffer.clear();
    colorBuffer.resize(colorBuffer.capacity());
}

void Tesselator::init(){
    clear();
    hasColor = false;
    hasTexture = false;
}

void Tesselator::tex(float u, float v){
    hasTexture = true;
    this->u = u;
    this->v = v;
}

void Tesselator::color(float r, float g, float b){
    hasColor = true;
    this->r = r;
    this->g = g;
    this->b = b;
}

void Tesselator::vertex(float x, float y, float z){
    vertexBuffer[vertices * 3 + 0] =  x;
    vertexBuffer[vertices * 3 + 1] =  y;
    vertexBuffer[vertices * 3 + 2] =  z;

    vertices += 1;

    if(vertices == MAX_VERTICES){
        flush();
    }
}
```

Caso alguém puder me dizer onde estou errando serei muito grato.

Comment: Não entendi. Você está portando um código com bugs?

Comment: Não, o código em Java funciona muito bem. Mas no código C++ não funciona =\. Tem alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Não, sinto muito. Só estava tentando esclarecer.

Comment: Será que alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Aguarde um pouco. Ainda dá tempo de aparecer mais gente. Muita gente só entra durante a noite.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado.

Comment: Ninguém... Isso está tão errado assim??

Comment: Pelo que entendi você esta tentando portar também a parte gráfica da aplicação que estava implementada em Java para C++/OpenGL? Neste caso você pode portar a lógica do programa mas quanto a parte gráfica é melhor reimplementar do zero em C++ usando a versão do programa em Java apenas
como inspiração para fazer uma interface igual.

Comment: @RodrigoSidneyPereira sim ele mesmo disse isso "portar o código de Java para C++"... O problema dele é que tem uma parte que ele não entendeu do código Java (o "BufferUtils" e o "FloatBuffer"), se ele entender isso ele provavelmente conseguirá portar, a pergunta pode tá meio mal explicada na parte de código e titulo, mas acho que deu pra entender o que ele precisa ;)